# How to match two long string in perl with special characters

Tags: perl

I would like to compare two string for equality.

```
      $txt  = 'Label Only - if no signs of leakage.';
      $txt1 = 'Label Only - if no signs of leakage';

      if($txt eq $txt1)
      {
        print "Both are equal";
      }
```

But since $txt1 doesn't contain period or dot it will not match.Can any please guide me how to escape period so that both variable $txt and $txt1 are equal.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it _always_ just a dot in the second of the two strings, or are we talking punctuation in general?

Comment: You can take a look at `substr` http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html

Comment: No. it can be or it can 't be

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to check if the two strings are equal, or differ only by a trailing period.

```
$str1 eq $str2 || "$str1." eq $str2 || $str1 eq "$str2."
```

or

```
( $str1 =~ s/\.\z//r ) eq ( $str2 =~ s/\.\z//r )   # 5.14+
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you use `\z` here as opposed to `$`?

Comment: @stevieb, Why would I use `$`? The OP didn't mention anything about newlines. Besides, adding support for newlines is far more complicated than using `$` instead of `\z` since you now have to consider the situation where one of the strings has a newline, but not the other. Rather than over-complicating things far beyond what the OP asked, I limited my answer to what the OP asked.

Comment: That's useful info. Taking a look in perlre now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The below removes thetrailing dot in `$txt` non-destructively using the `/r` regex modifier before the comparison. This feature was introduced in [perl v5.14](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html).

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $txt  = 'Label Only - if no signs of leakage.';
my $txt1 = 'Label Only - if no signs of leakage';

if($txt =~ s/\.$//r eq $txt1){
    print "Both are equal";
}
```

Update: Fixed to only strip a trailing period.

Comment: While it considers `abc.` and `abc` to be the same, it considers `abc` and `abc.` to be different.

Comment: I've changed it to remove only a `.` at the end of the string, as OP didn't mention clearly what they were after. Thanks for pointing that out @ikegami

Comment: Right. I just stated what you're doing so they can judge if it's right for them.